# Haproxy set samesession cookie depeding on the user agent

Tags: acl, haproxy

In the haproxy I need to have the ability to set the samesite for cookies depending on the user agent as some old versions of chrome does not seam to support this flag and then I need to delete.

I have tried the following config but it doesn't seam to want to work:

```
        acl old_chrome capture.req.hdr(User-Agent) ^.+Chrome\/(((5[1-9])|6[0-6]))\..+$
        http-response replace-header Set-Cookie: SERVERID; SameSite=None if !old_chrome
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I have made it work with the following configurations:

```
declare capture request len 40000
http-request capture req.fhdr(User-Agent) len 64
http-response replace-header Set-Cookie (JSESSIONID=[^;]*);(.*) \1;\ Path=/;\ Secure;\ HttpOnly;\ SameSite=None if !{ capture.req.hdr(1) -i -m reg ^.+Chrome\/(((5[1-9])|6[0-6]))\..+$ }
```